# Export/import stack trace in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

In Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to export and import a stack trace as a file, for debugging purposes?

Currently, we inlcude the stack trace in an email, but it would be easier on the eyes and mind if we were able somehow pull it in to visual studio and interact with it like normal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has an option to [Open a Stack Trace](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Navigation/stackTraceExplorer.html) in Visual Studio

Comment: I'm not sure. Reading that, I'm not clear if it fits the bill. I'm looking for the ability to export the details of an exception to a small file on a **live** piece of software (a website), which can be emailed and subsequently imported/opened in VS2010.